# Unusual Time format in date and time column

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I have the below date format stored as factors as one of the columns in the Data frame:

```
2017-02-19T21:10:18.664+00:00
2017-03-10T21:40:50.398+00:00
```

Sample Data:

```
head(dataset$local_end_datetime)
[1] 2017-02-19T21:10:18.664+00:00 2017-02-19T21:10:38.418+00:00
[3] 2017-03-10T21:40:50.398+00:00 2017-03-11T16:41:43.339+00:00
[5] 2017-03-10T21:43:31.092+00:00 2017-03-10T21:34:36.065+00:00
```

I need to split the same for date and time. I can find get the date extracted using below:

```
dataset$Date <- as.Date(dataset$local_end_datetime)
```

How can I extract the time from above format? I don't know regular expressions.

Comment: `lubridate::ymd_hms("2017-02-19T21:10:18.664+00:00")`

Comment: These are [combined date and time representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), including a timezone offset (`+00:00`, in this case, means "zero hours of difference from UTC"), so nothing unusual about them.

Comment: @Hugo unusual in terms of how its structured , I havent come across this and couldnt find any ways to go about it . Thanks so much for pointers .

Comment: @d.b thank you much

Comment: Neha - you should write it up what you did as an answer and post it and then mark it correct. It will help people down the line and can attract upvotes then too. People love these kind of focused questions and then focused answers. Even though a lot of the powers that be see them as "duplicates".

Comment: @MikeWise Thank you for great suggestion

Answer (score 1):

```
Library Lubridate is quite powerful when it comes to manipulating dates

dataset$datetime <- lubridate::ymd_hms(dataset$local_end_datetime)
dataset$Local_Date <- as.Date(dataset$datetime)
dataset$Local_Time <- format(dataset$datetime,"%H:%M:%S")
```